# Problem with building an ANN for Iris Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning. I have been trying to get this code working but the loss is stuck as 1.12 and is neither increasing or decreasing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('Iris.csv')

#for rncoding label
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
dataset["Labels"] = encoder.fit_transform(dataset["Species"])


X = dataset.iloc[:,1:5]
Y = dataset['Labels']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

X_train = np.array(X_train).astype(np.float32)
X_test  = np.array(X_test).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.array(y_train).astype(np.float32)
y_test  = np.array(y_test).astype(np.float32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(4,), activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
r = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)
```

Comment: Hey does the answer solve your query? Do update if the suggestions in the answer fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classification problem where you have to predict the class of Iris plant ([source](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris)). You have specified [mse](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/#meansquarederror-class) loss which stands for 'Mean Squared Error'. It measures the average deviation of predicted values from actual values. The square ensures you penalize a large deviation higher than a small deviation. This loss is used for regression problems when you have to predict a continuous value like price, clicks, sales etc.

A  few suggestions that will help are:

1. Change the loss to a classification loss function. [categorical_cross_entropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-function) is a good choice here. Without going into too many details, in classification problems model outputs the score of a particular sample belonging to a class. The [softmax](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/softmax/) function used by you converts these scores to normalized probabilities. The cross-entropy loss ensures that your model is penalized when it gives a high probability to the wrong class
2. Try standardizing your data with 0 mean and unit variance. This helps the model convergence.

You may refer to [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) article for building a neural network for Iris dataset.